# Expression is not captured in the first run

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to query for the 'default' expression used in imagePlane node with the following code:

```py
# Part01
img = cmds.imagePlane()
frame_ext_attr = "{0}.useFrameExtension".format(img[0])
cmds.setAttr(frame_ext_attr, True)

# Part02
print '>>> ', cmds.listConnections("{0}.frameExtension".format(img[0]))
```

If I am running the above code block as a whole, `part02` returns me a `None` result even though there is indeed an expression in the `frameExtension` attribute. Unless I run the code block another time, will then I get something in return.

However, if I run the code in 2 parts, `part01` first then `part02`, I will be getting a result such as `['expression1']`

My question here is - why are the returned results so different?
I have also tried using some mel-based commands such as `refreshAE` or `updateAE <node path>`, in hope that the (whole) code block will be able to capture the expression in the first run, but it is not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `cmds.imagePlane()` again in Part02. The effect of `cmds.setAttr()` might not extend to the previously captured value in `img`.

Comment: But wouldn't that create another new plane? P.S: I added that command as you have mentioned, still, it is returning me `None`

Comment: Well, it was worth a try :-)